# FFMPEG/DASH-LL creates audio and video chunks at different rates; player is confused (404 errors)

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, dash.js, shaka

I'm trying to create a MPEG-DASH "live" stream from a static file to test various low latency modes.  The DASH muxer in FFmpeg creates two AdaptationSets, one for video chunks and one for audio chunks.

However, the audio and video chunk files are not created at the same rate (should they be?).  ie, here `stream0` are the video chunks and `stream1` are the audio chunks.  After a few seconds of running, the webroot directory contains:

```
chunk-stream0-00001.m4s  chunk-stream1-00001.m4s  
chunk-stream0-00002.m4s  chunk-stream1-00002.m4s  
chunk-stream0-00003.m4s  chunk-stream1-00003.m4s  
chunk-stream0-00004.m4s  chunk-stream1-00004.m4s  
                         chunk-stream1-00005.m4s  
                         chunk-stream1-00006.m4s  
                         chunk-stream1-00007.m4s  
                         chunk-stream1-00008.m4s  
                         chunk-stream1-00009.m4s  
master.mpd  
init-stream0.m4s  
init-stream1.m4s
```

The stream doesn't load (or play) on either `dash.js` or shaka-player and there are lots of `404 (Not Found)` errors for the video chunks.  The player is requesting chunks from both stream0 and stream1 in sequence, ie, stream0-001 + stream1-001, then stream0-002 + stream1-002 and so on.

But since stream0 only goes from 001 to 004, there are lots of 404 errors as it tries to load stream0-005 through 009.

The gap gets wider after letting FFmpeg run for a while. eg, stream0 is 62 to 75 but stream1 is 174 to 187.  Reloading the player page at this point fails with `dash.all.debug.js:15615 [2055][FragmentController] No video bytes to push or stream is inactive.` and shows 404 errors stream0 *chunk 188* (which doesn't exist yet!)

[image]

The FFmpeg command was adopted from [DASH streaming from the top-down](https://lynne.ee/dash-streaming-from-the-top-down.html):

```
ffmpeg -re -i /mnt/swdevel/TestStreams/H264/ThreeHourMovie.mp4 \
-c:v libx264 -x264-params keyint=120:scenecut=0 -b:v 1M -c:a copy \
-f dash -dash_segment_type mp4 \
 -seg_duration 2 \
 -target_latency 3 \
 -frag_type duration \
 -frag_duration 0.2 \
 -window_size 10 \
 -extra_window_size 3 \
 -streaming 1 \
 -ldash 1 \
 -use_template 1 \
 -use_timeline 0 \
 -write_prft 1 \
 -fflags +nobuffer+flush_packets \
 -format_options "movflags=+cmaf" \
 -utc_timing_url "/pelican/testPlayers/time.php" \
 master.mpd
```

And the `dash.js` player code is very simple:

```
const srcUrl = "../ottWebRoot/playerTest/master.mpd"; 

var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();

let autoPlay = false;
player.initialize(document.querySelector("#videoTagId"), srcUrl, autoPlay);

player.updateSettings(
{
    streaming :
    {
        lowLatencyEnabled : true,
        liveDelay : 2,
        jumpGaps : true,
        jumpLargeGaps : true,
        smallGapLimit : 1.5,
    }
});
```

To provide the `UTCTiming` element in the manifest, the small `time.php` URL returns a UTC time from the web server:

```
<?php
    print gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
?>
```

(It also shows 404 errors for the latest stream1/audio chunk, that's likely a different problem)

I'm not sure what to try next.  Any and suggestions greatly appreciated.

**EDIT I**

The suggestion by [@Anonymous Coward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6718124/anonymous-coward) to change the key interval improved things a lot.  The chunks for stream0 and stream1 are in lock-step and have identical sequence numbers.

However, there are still many 404 errors, both on initial page load (without pressing play) and during playback.

I ran `watch -n 1 ls -lt <webRootFolder` and compared side-by-side to the errors in the browser console.  It's hard to compare but it *looks* like the browser is trying to fetch files "on the play edge" which haven't yet been created by FFmpeg.  See the pic below.

How do I instruct the browser to wait just a bit more before fetching the edge chunks?

[image]

**EDIT II**

Using `shaka-player` instead of `dash.js` plays properly without 404 errors.  Configured as:

```
    player.configure(
    {
        streaming: 
        {
            lowLatencyMode: true,
            inaccurateManifestTolerance: 0,
            rebufferingGoal: 0.1,
        }
        
    });
```

**Client**

- MacOS 10.12
- dash.js latest 3.2.2
- Chrome 79, Safari 12, FireFox v?

**Server**

- Apache 2.4.37
- PHP 7.2.4 (for time function only)
- Centos 8

(For reference, here is the mpd file generated by FFmpeg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd"
    profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
    type="dynamic"
    minimumUpdatePeriod="PT500S"
    availabilityStartTime="2021-05-24T14:50:00.263Z"
    publishTime="2021-05-24T15:22:45.335Z"
    timeShiftBufferDepth="PT50.0S"
    maxSegmentDuration="PT2.0S"
    minBufferTime="PT5.0S">
    <ProgramInformation>
    </ProgramInformation>
    <ServiceDescription id="0">
        <Latency target="3000" referenceId="0"/>
    </ServiceDescription>
    <Period id="0" start="PT0.0S">
        <AdaptationSet id="0" contentType="video" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true" frameRate="24/1" maxWidth="1280" maxHeight="682" par="15:8" lang="und">
            <Resync dT="200000" type="0"/>
            <Representation id="0" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64081f" bandwidth="1000000" width="1280" height="682" sar="1023:1024">
                <ProducerReferenceTime id="0" inband="true" type="captured" wallClockTime="2021-05-24T14:50:00.263Z" presentationTime="0">
                    <UTCTiming schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:utc:http-xsdate:2014" value="/pelican/testPlayers/time.php"/>
                </ProducerReferenceTime>
                <Resync dT="5000000" type="1"/>
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000000" duration="2000000" availabilityTimeOffset="1.800" availabilityTimeComplete="false" initialization="init-stream$RepresentationID$.m4s" media="chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet id="1" contentType="audio" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true" lang="und">
            <Resync dT="200000" type="0"/>
            <Representation id="1" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="116317" audioSamplingRate="48000">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2" />
                <ProducerReferenceTime id="1" inband="true" type="captured" wallClockTime="2021-05-24T14:50:00.306Z" presentationTime="0">
                    <UTCTiming schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:utc:http-xsdate:2014" value="/pelican/testPlayers/time.php"/>
                </ProducerReferenceTime>
                <Resync dT="21333" type="1"/>
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000000" duration="2000000" availabilityTimeOffset="1.800" availabilityTimeComplete="false" initialization="init-stream$RepresentationID$.m4s" media="chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
    <UTCTiming schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:utc:http-xsdate:2014" value="/pelican/testPlayers/time.php"/>
</MPD>
```

Comment: If it plays in Shaka but not dash.js, it would be good to raise a bug with the dash.js team as I know they have worked hard on LL-DASH: https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input, `ThreeHourMovie.mp4`, has a frame rate of 24Hz (see `AdaptationSet@frameRate`), so setting `keyint` to `120` will give an IDR every five seconds at the output of x264.

You are instructing the DASH muxer (via `seg_duration`) to output and signal 2s segments, but this isn't possible since a segment must start with an IDR (as mentioned in the guide you linked). So the muxer outputs 5s segments, but signals 2s in the manifest, which is clearly incorrect.

Change `keyint` to the correct multiple of `seg_duration` (ie `keyint=48` in this case), and it will probably start working.

Comment: Thanks!  That improved it a lot.  However, still a problem with 404 errors when fetching the "edge" files.  See EDIT I in the main question.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I changed `liveDelay` in the player but still the same...

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same with Exoplayer. However, if I set the value
**"-use_timeline 1"** the problem is not there anymore. However, with use_timeline set to 1, you will not have partial segments on the template. I am not sure this is a bug of ffmpeg.